# iPhone 5 screen size black bars

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5, iphone-5, iphone-4, screen-size

I am having problems in making my iPhone 4 (3.5 inch screen) work on iPhone 5 screen. I have already tried to import Default-568h@2x.png image for a launch image and it works properly in simulator, and when run on real device there are black bars on top and bottom of the screen. Does anybody have similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

All apps that do not include the Default-568h@2x.png file are displayed in a letter box. Include the Default-568h@2x.png will make your app fill the screen on 4" retina devices.

hope this fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could have tested this issue in simulator itself . 
There are two possible solutions for this. Listed below:

1. In the 'Simulated Metrics' section of `UIVIew`'s attributes inspector, you can choose between 3,5" or 4" sizes. Choose 3,5", and make your views and subviews resizable .This will make it automatically scale your view to fit iPhone 5's screen.

2.OR you can make use of **Auto Layout** (constraints) with the deployment target of iOS 6+.

Hope this will solve the issue.